# Is there a graceful way to "simulate" passing a getter by reference?

Tags: javascript, class, pass-by-reference, getter

I have the following class...

```js
class Order {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
  get subtotal() { return this.items.reduce((sum, {price}) => sum+price, 0); }
}
```

...and a component called `PaymentSummary` in which I'd like to reference the `Order.subtotal`. However, as is the case with getters, I'm only able to pass `subtotal` *by value*.

Pseudo/simplified:

```js
let order = new Order();                //subtotal: 15.00
let paymentSummary = new PaymentSummary(order.subtotal);
order.items.push( {price: 100.00} );    //subtotal: 115.00

console.log( paymentSummary.subtotal ); //15.00
```

The obvious solution would be to make `subtotal` a *method* instead of a *getter*, like so:

```js
class Order {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
  function subtotal() { return this.items.reduce((sum, {price}) => sum+price, 0); }
}
```

Now I can pass `Order.subtotal` as a function reference and we're set.

**But**, is this the *only* solution?

Perhaps I'm being overly-cautious or simply going about this the wrong way, but it just seems like a smell that the order data is now a mixed bag of properties and methods.

I'd considered passing the entire `order` but given its size/complexity (multiple nested classes, with their own nested classes, etc), that seemed like a bad idea.

Given that SO requires specific questions, I suppose my question boils down to this: Is there a way to pass a reference to a calculated value such that retrieving it doesn't require *executing* it?

Comment: Passing the method will not be enough, you probably would want to bind it.

Comment: Why not just pass your instance of `Order`. Then the function can just call the getter directly.

Comment: @Intervalia One thing I should've mentioned is that the `PaymentSummary` is one of the properties of the `Order`. Is it reasonable to do `this.paymentSummary = new PaymentSummary(this)` within the `Order` constructor?

Comment: @Santi Yes, you can do that, but if you have such a circular reference you need to beware of your `PaymentSummary` constructor not using properties of the half-initialised `Order` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass a reference to a calculated value such that retrieving it doesn't require executing it?

No. Passing a function or passing an object with a getter property are your only options. Both are totally reasonable, although the function makes it obvious that the result may change - an object changing "on its own" could be confusing.

Comment: I appreciate it. That is the route I will go then!

Comment: If `PaymentSummary` was *part* of the order, e.g. the `Order` constructor had `this.paymentSummary = new PaymentSummary(...)`, does that open up any doors? Perhaps something similar to `super` that allows access to the parent or root instance? I imagine not but figured I'd ask.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as a "parent" or "root instance" - an object could be contained in multiple other objects, or in none. However, passing the individual `Orders` to the `PaymentSummary` sound just fine - a summary consists of multiple orders.

Comment: In this case a `PaymentSummary` is actually just *one* order, but I believe your point stands. A payment summary is a component that shows all the payments, subtotal, tax, etc. I was trying to make a ViewModel for it by passing just the information it needed, however it sounds like I may be better off scrapping that and just passing the entire order to the component. I genuinely appreciate your help and sticking with me on this even after you'd already answered.